# CodeIgniter REST Server Library Configuration

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I'm having some trouble trying to configure the RestServer library for CodeIgniter (https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php).

//EDIT
I'm using Code Igniter Version 2.1.3

Whenever I try to access a model from a Controller, it returns an error saying:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Dan::$dM
```

My controller looks like this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

// This can be removed if you use __autoload() in config.php OR use Modular Extensions
require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Dan extends REST_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('dan_model','dM',TRUE);
    }

    public function ptest_get()
    {
        //$this->load->model('dan_model','dM');
        //var_dump($this->dM);
        $test = $this->dM->testSum();
        //$test = 1;

      $this->response($test, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code

    }

}

?>
```

I have configured everything that the documentation states, I have loaded the database module in the autoload.php, I have tried loading the model in the construct and in the function but it always returns the error. The only solution I have found (which is not efficiente) is in the autoload.php file configure to load all the models since the beginning (thing that we don't want because of performance).

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Models
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['model'] = array('model1', 'model2');
|
*/

$autoload['model'] = array('finder_model');
```

Could anyone point me if I'm missing some configuration or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here and it should work.

Comment: try to change `$this->load->model('dan_model');` and `$test = $this->dan_model->testSum();` just for debugging

Comment: Hi, I changed that and $test is equal to NULL, it seems it isn't loading the model.

Comment: which version of codeigniter you are using?

Comment: I had already added in my description it's CI 2.3.1